# convert list of Tupel into list of lists

Tags: haskell

Hey guys I want to be able to change a list of  tuple in a list of lists . Here is what I am thinking:

```
pairToList :: (a, a) -> [a]
pairToList (x,y) = [x,y]

listoflists :: [(a, a)] -> [[a]]
listoflists xs = [pairToList (a, a) | a <- xs]
```

The first function works perfectly which is change Tupels into list but the second one doesn't not work, I tried to write it like that.

```
listoflists :: [(a, a)] -> [[a]]
listoflists xs = [pairToList (a, a) | (a,a) <- xs]
```

I am new with using comprehension of lists that contain Tuples.

Comment: Worth noting that you can just write `listOfLists = map pairToList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second attempt,

```
listoflists xs = [pairToList (a, a) | (a,a) <- xs]
```

the part `(a,a) <- xs` is illegal, since it tries to define variable `a` mutliple times. For instance, if `xs = [(1,2)]` then the generator `(a,a) <- [(1,2)]` would define `a` as `1` and `2` at the same time which makes no sense.

You need to use different variables, e.g. `(a1,a2) <- xs`.

---

In the first attempt,

```
listoflists xs = [pairToList (a, a) | a <- xs]
```

`a` represents a generic pair taken from `xs`. Because of that `(a,a)` will be a pair-of-pairs. Hence, `pairToList (a,a)` will produce a list-of-pairs, which is not what you wanted. You could fix this by directly calling `pairToList a` instead.